# Not understanding access_rules for ejabberd

Tags: acl, ejabberd, access-rules

I have one machine that runs an Elgg portal, which contains a plugin that untilizes converse.js as XMPP-client and on the same machine I run a ejabberd XMPP-server.

Normal operation would be that the plugin synchronizes users/password/details from Elgg portal to ejabberd-server. This fails with the following error message:

```
...
2020-07-13 10:04:58.665 [warning] <0.1058.0>@ejabberd_xmlrpc:build_fault_response:238 Error -118 A problem '{error,access_rules_unauthorized}' occurred executing the command check_account with arguments [{user,<<"UserName">>},{host,<<"example.com">>}]{name,<<"FN">>},
 {content,<<"My Name">>}]
...
```

I guess I have to fiddle with the access_rules for xmlrpc.
In my `ejabberd.yml` I have the following lines (of course there are much more):

```
...
acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@example.com"
  xmlrpc_access:
    user:
      - "admin@example.com"
access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  xmlrpc_access:
    allow: xmlrpc_access
...
```

Can you help me to understand what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few weeks ago I checked how configuration works, and updated the documentation acordingly. Try the example configuration provided in https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/listen/#ejabberd-xmlrpc